# How to: Password Protect Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I have website that is Hosted in a Azure App Service. are there any options in azure so that I can put a password on the website. Ideally without changing the websites code.

Just a basic password or user name and password, doesn't need to be google or facebook login or AD login.

It is a .net based website and I have seen a few options to do this, but it means I have to change the code of the website in someway or another.

Surely with all that sophisticated cloud technology, I can go in to the portal and set a password at a server level? - Or is the only way to make some kind of change to the application?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to enable Basic Authentication for Azure Web Apps with some settings in the **applicationHost.xdt**. You can load some modules in this file on the start of your Web App.

**Steps:**

- Navigate to your WebApp in the Azure Portal
- In the left menu, search for the header **Development Tools** an select **Advanced Tools** (Kudu)
- Use the **Debug Console > CMD** tool, to navigate to the WebApp directory: **\home\site**
- Create a file named: **applicationHost.xdt**
- Paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <add name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
        <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <rule name="BasicAuthentication" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}" pattern="^Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" statusReason="Unauthorized" statusDescription="Unauthorized" />
            <serverVariables>
              <set name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" value="Basic realm=Project" />
            </serverVariables>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

- Change the Basic Auth to your liking (default in example is: user:password)
- Make sure the web.config rewrite rules don't contain `<clear />` as this wil remove the effects from the applicationHost.xdt file
- Save the file and Stop and Start your WebApp (a simple *Restart* will **not** suffice)

**Notes:**

- Not sure if this works on Linux based WebApps..
- You can add this step to you're deployment pipelines by using FTP
- **Update:** I've noticed issues with applicationHost.xdt while using it on secondary Web App slots. Only the primary slot seems to work.

**PS:** [Cross-post from my answer here.](https://serverfault.com/a/1057632/623226)

Comment: regarding the Linux app plan: the approach above cannot work with Linux according to this [article](https://anthonychu.ca/post/jekyll-azure-app-service-linux/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service.

*Authentication/Authorization was previously known as Easy Auth.*

> Azure App Service provides built-in authentication and authorization support, so you can sign in users and access data by writing minimal or no code in your web app, RESTful API, and mobile back end, and also Azure Functions. This article describes how App Service helps simplify authentication and authorization for your app.
>
> Source: [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).

**EDIT:**
The above is a solution to have a password protected App Service *without changing any code whatsoever*. At this point there is no alternative, as you can see in the open feedback issue [Allow HTTP Basic authentication on basic apps](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12805239-allow-http-basic-authentication-on-basic-apps)

> Hi everyone, we understand the demand for this feature, but we do not plan to support authentication at this level. We suggest using EasyAuth for this scenario.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

**EDIT 2:**

> This method forces the user to use google or facebook, etc...

This is not true. You can also create a user in your Azure Active Directory and use that one with Easy Auth. The username would be something like `username@<YOUR-TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: This method forces the user to use google or facebook, etc... I just want a simple hard coded password.

Comment: @AyoAdesina Please have a look at the updated answer. I understand this might not be the answer you wanted, it *is* the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### For those still searching for a Linux Azure WebApp solution...

I know this question is fairly old at this point, but it was still relevant for my situation.  I spent a lot of time researching this and it was difficult to find a simple Apache type .htaccess/.htpasswd equivalent solution on my **Linux** Nginx Azure WebApp when the newer PHP WebApp images switched from Apache to Nginx.  I think this approach with some slight modifications to account for .NET vs PHP could have worked for the original poster as a solution with zero code changes.  I'll also acknowledge the .htpasswd approach, although easy, is generally frowned upon with so many other more secure options available.

#### Setup

Let's start by creating the folders and files we need:

1. Through the Azure Portal log onto the WebApp's web SSH, the url is in the format: https://mywebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host
2. Run the following commands to create the folder structure and files we will use:

```bash
# install the apache2-utils plug-in, note this can be removed
# on a WebApp restart, but we'll deal with that later
apt install apache2-utils

# create a new folder with the /home directory to persist
# our modified custom copy of the Nginx "default" config file
# note that nothing outside of the /home directory persists
# when a WebApp stops/starts
mkdir /home/custom-nginx-config

# copy the nginx "default" config file to our new folder
cp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default /home/custom-nginx-config/default

# create a folder to store the .htpasswd file
mkdir /home/site/PW

# create a valid .htpasswd file, pass it the path where we
# want to create the file and the username
# it will prompt you to type in a password
htpasswd -c /home/site/PW/.htpasswd myuser
```

#### Customize Our Copy of the Nginx Config

Now we need to customize our copy of the Nginx "default" config file. To do that edit the copied config file we created in the location `/home/custom-nginx-config/default`. Edit it using your preferred method of editing WebApp files.

*EXAMPLE 1*

As the original poster asked, if you simply want to password protect the entire website note where I've modified my copied Nginx config file with `# START: CUSTOM EDITS` and `# END: CUSTOM EDITS` notation (all other code was what was copied over):

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com; 
    port_in_redirect off;
    # START: CUSTOM EDITS
    auth_basic "Website Is Protected";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/site/PW/.htpasswd;
    # END: CUSTOM EDITS

    location / {      
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        # START: CUSTOM EDITS
        auth_basic "Website Is Protected";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/site/PW/.htpasswd;
        # END: CUSTOM EDITS

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

*EXAMPLE 2*

If you instead want to password protect one folder and everything under it on a website, note the edits within the `# START: CUSTOM EDITS` and `# END: CUSTOM EDITS` notations. This example is password protecting everything under an example folder named `folder-to-protect`:

```json
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com; 
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {            
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
    }
    
    # START: CUSTOM EDITS
    location /folder-to-protect {
        auth_basic "Folder Is Protected";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/site/PW/.htpasswd;
    }
    
    location ~* .*\/folder-to-protect\/.*\.php {
        auth_basic "Folder Is Protected";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/site/PW/.htpasswd;
        
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }       
    # END: CUSTOM EDITS

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

A couple of notes about the customized Nginx "default" config file in this second example:

- Someone that is more familiar with the syntax may be able to optimize this, it seems heavy handed.
- In my testing this protects `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect` and all folders and files under it such as `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect/index.php`, `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect/sub-folder/`, `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect/sub-folder/index.php` and `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect/sub-folder/test.gif`
- With any testing you do ensure you test both the root path such as `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect` but also files such as `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect/index.php` and `http://myexamplewebshite.com/folder-to-protect/sub-folder/test.gif`
- The first added block `location /folder-to-protect {` protects the folders and sub-folders in the URL structure but it was still serving the .php files without a password.  I think it is because the existing block at the bottom of the config file with `location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {` was being envoked. So I copied this block and made a modification to add the .htpasswd info with a location pattern match of `location ~* .*\/folder-to-protect\/.*\.php`
- It was also important to put the edited blocks higher in the file, it seems to help them override the ones lower in the file that were serving the file without the need for the password.

*RAPID CONFIG TESTING*

You can test your changes more quickly without having to stop/start the WebApp constantly by running these commands in the SSH web session to copy the modified config file and restart nginx:

```bash
cp /home/custom-nginx-config/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
service nginx restart
```

#### Persist Our Edits Every Time the WebApp Starts Up

Since the WebApp state outside of the /home directory gets wiped out every time the WebApp restarts, we need to do the following every time the WebApp starts up:

1. Re-install the apache2-utils plug-in
2. Copy our custom modified Nginx "default" configuration file within the /home directory to overwrite the Nginx configuration file
3. Restart the Nginx service to pickup the new config

To do this, go to your WebApp in the Azure Portal and go to the following configuration setting: Configuration -> General settings -> Startup Command
Within the Startup Command textbox paste the following command:

```bash
apt install apache2-utils; cp /home/custom-nginx-config/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; service nginx restart
```

[image: Startup Command]

Fully stop and then start the WebApp to test this, don't just do a WebApp restart.

#### References and Options

With this approach I think you have a lot of options to customize what you are protecting such as an entire site (*EXAMPLE 1*), a folder and everything under it (*EXAMPLE 2*), just a single file, or likely anything in-between using the Nginx location pattern matching. I could not have put this working solution together without the following references, and they have some other good ideas for how to customize your approach:

- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/configure-nginx-for-php-8-linux-azure-app-service/ba-p/3069373
- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-password-protect-directory-with-nginx-htpasswd-authentication/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1282899/how-does-startup-commands-work-on-an-azure-app-ser
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-location-directive
- https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/nginx-location-examples/