# Azure Web App for Containers: how to password protect

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-container-service

How can I **password protect** a demo web application deployed on Azure *Web App for Containers*?

We don't require elaborate user management right now. A single user with a standard password would suffice.

Thanks

Comment: [How to: Password Protect Azure App service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588030/how-to-password-protect-azure-app-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   You can password protect the **‘Azure Web App for Containers’** for a visitor or any member who tries to access the **configuration settings, application settings and general settings of that Azure web app**. To do so, kindly refer to the below documentation link for building a pipeline through Azure DevOps and creating an Azure web app for containers successfully through yaml file: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-docker-webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml

In the above link, you will have to `deploy the sample web app to container through the ‘YAML’ code but before that, you will have to build and publish a Docker image to Azure Container Registry and retrieve the image from the container registry by uploading that image through Azure DevOps via Github`.

•   Once the above is done, then kindly navigate to the **‘Web App for Container’** created through the Azure portal, then go to **‘Settings --> Configuration --> General settings --> Password protection section --> select Protect staging environments only or Protect both production and staging environments to protect all environments --> Enter a password in ‘Visitor Password’ with required password parameters --> Confirm visitor password --> Save’**

For more information, kindly refer to the documentation below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/password-protection

Thus, by following the above document steps, you can configure password protection for your azure web app deployed on container for a single user/visitor.